# There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference

Tags: dll, reference, .net-assembly, dynamics-gp, gac-msil

I am using eConnect SDK 11.0. I have a windows service app in which i had added reference of GP sdk.

1) Microsoft.Dynamics.GP.eConnect.dll

2) Microsoft.Dynamics.GP.eConnect.Serialization.dll

When i build my project it had built successfully but gave me the following warning

1) There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "Microsoft.Dynamics.GP.eConnect, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=AMD64", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

2) There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "Microsoft.Dynamics.GP.eConnect.Serialization Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=AMD64", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.

Any idea what can i do to fix this issue? I am trying to build my project in Release 64 settings

Comment: The assembly you are using contains native x64 code.  It is giving you the warning because your project targets AnyCPU.  It can't be "any cpu", this code is only going to run on a 64-bit processor and a 64-bit operating system.  Not hard to come by these days.  Right-click your EXE project > Properties > Build tab.  Change the Platform target setting to x64, untick the Prefer 32-bit checkbox if you see it.  You probably already did that for the Debug configuration, also do that for the Release configuration.

Comment: @HansPassant .. Thanks a lot Hans. It worked for me

Comment: Hi @Developer, I am trying to build the sample lead web services project and having issues in config file, could you please guide me?

Comment: Hi @elmo can you please elaborate what issues you are facing in config file.

Comment: Warning 1 The 'configSource' attribute is not allowed. 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics\GPWebServicesSDK\v16\Samples\LeadWebService\LeadWebService\InstallLeadSecurityMetadata\
InstallLeadSecurityMetadata\app.config 7 15 InstallLeadSecurityMetadata